# How to add a contact-photo to google-contact with appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, photo, google-contacts-api

Creating or updating a google contact with appscript is well documented. However I find no information on how to add a photo to a contact within appscript.

Situation:
A google sheet row with: Name, Address, ImgSrcUrl
each in a separate column.

How can I create the contact and add a Photo to it? Source Code snippet below:

```
/******************************************************* */
function addContact() {
/******************************************************* */
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var active_row = cell.getRow();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const CNAME = 3;
  const CADDR = 4;
  const CEMAIL = 5;
  const CIMGURL = 6;
  var name = range.getCell(active_row, CNAME).getValue();
  var addr = range.getCell(active_row, CADDR).getValue();
  var email = range.getCell(active_row, CEMAIL).getValue();
  var imgurl = range.getCell(active_row, CIMGURL).getValue();

  contact = ContactsApp.createContact(first_name, last_name, email);  // create contact
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to add the photo to the existing contact.

  - I thought that `a contact-photo` you think might be `coverPhotos`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

Although I checked whether your goal can be achieve using [Contact service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts), unfortunately, I couldn't find it. So, in your situation, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to use People API. When People API is used for this, the script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable People API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the variables.

```
function myFunction() {
  const familyName = "###";
  const givenName = "###";
  const emailAddress = "###";
  const imageUrl = "###";

  // 1. Create contact.
  const resource1 = { emailAddresses: [{ value: emailAddress }], names: [{ familyName: familyName, givenName: givenName }] }
  const resourceName = People.People.createContact(resource1).resourceName;
  
  // 2. Add cover photo to the created contact.
  const resource2 = { photoBytes: Utilities.base64Encode(UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getContent()), personFields: "coverPhotos" };
  People.People.updateContactPhoto(resource2, resourceName);
}
```

- In this script, it supposes that your image URL is the direct link of the image file. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- When you want to add the cover photo to the existing contact, you can also use the following script. In this sample script, the existing contact is searched using the email address.

  ```
    function myFunction2() {
      const emailAddress = "###";
      const imageUrl = "###";

      // 1. Search contact using the email address.
      const contacts = People.People.searchContacts({ query: emailAddress, readMask: "emailAddresses,names" }).results.filter(c => c.person.emailAddresses.map(m => m.value).includes(emailAddress));

      // 2. Add cover photo to the retrieved contact.
      if (contacts.length > 0) {
        const resource2 = { photoBytes: Utilities.base64Encode(UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getContent()), personFields: "coverPhotos" };
        People.People.updateContactPhoto(resource2, contacts[0].person.resourceName);
      }
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: people.createContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact)
- [Method: people.updateContactPhoto](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContactPhoto)
- [Method: people.searchContacts](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tanaike. I tested the code and with several sites / images. It does the job. 

However i encountered one particular site where UrlFetchApp.fetch(img503.jpg) generated a 503 error response (note that at wget img503.jpg works fine with the same image). I might post this as a follow up question.

Comment: @skaleio Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, when I saw your new post, I would like to check it.